# Microsoft Azure NotificationHubs Installation failed

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, azure-notificationhub

i got this problem when i try to install this package Microsoft Azure NotificationHubs in visual studio 2015 enterprise.
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsKfi.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yVy2.png)

Comment: Seriously: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell me how you install the package? Do you install as the similar  steps below?

1. In Visual Studio, add a new Visual C# Windows Classic Desktop project to the current solution using the Console Application project template. Name the project `ConsoleNotificationhubs`.
2. In Solution Explorer, right-click the `ConsoleNotificationhubs` project, and then click `Manage NuGet Packages`.
3. In the `NuGet Package Manager` window, search for `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs`, click Install, and accept the terms of use.

Please note that this package requires .Net Framework 4.5 Full Profile.
If you install successfully, you will get the information like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to install the Azure Notification Hubs package in a [UAP app](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/03/02/a-first-look-at-the-windows-10-universal-app-platform/). **You don't need to do it**.

Just configure the notification channel per the [doc referenced in the comments](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/) (cc: [*Brendan Green*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1567352/brendan-green)).